# Delete unused path range indexes in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there any way to find out unused path range indexes in marklogic or it's last usage..?

Answer (score 0):

such as feature is not yet supported by MarkLogic.

Alternately you can perform a search operation throughout your API code to determine whether the path range indexes is used or not.

A simple query can be:

```
let $docs := fn:doc(cts:uri-match("/yourapipathhere"))[1]
return fn:contains($docs,"/xmldocument/yourpathrangeindex")
```

I know this code is kind of brute force, but currently this seems an option.